# Do contraction mappings contract everything by the same amount?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The definition of a contraction mapping is:

> "A contraction mapping $T$ on $(X,d)$ is a continuous function $T:X\to X$ such that $\forall x,y\in X$ we have that $d(T(x),T(y))≤qd(x,y)$ where $q\in(0,1)$"

So if I'm reading this correctly, there are some points $x,y$ such that the distance shrinks by a mulpiple of $q$ after the mapping, but there may be another pair of points that shrinks by even more, so not all points shrink by the same ratio, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Not all points need to shrink by the same ratio, as long as they all shrink.

Answer (score 1):

> so not all points shrink by the same ratio, is that correct?

Yes, that's correct. Here's an example.

For a given function $f:X\to X$, assuming $x\neq y$ the ratio would be

$$r(x,y)=\frac{d(T(x),T(y))}{d(x,y)}$$

So your question can be restated as: $r(x,y)$ need not be constant, right? Yes.

Consider $X=[1,\infty)$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. The ratio is then

$$r(x,y)=\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|}{|x-y|}=$$

$$=\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\cdot |\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|}{|x-y|\cdot|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|}=\frac{|x-y|}{|x-y|\cdot|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|}=\frac{1}{|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|}$$

Since $x,y\in[1,\infty)$ the ratio above cannot exceed $\frac{1}{2}$. Meaning $\sqrt{x}$ is a contraction on $[1,\infty)$ with $q=\frac{1}{2}$. But the ratio $r(x,y)$ clearly is not constant, it depends on $x$ and $y$, e.g. $r(4,9)=\frac{1}{5}$, $r(9,16)=\frac{1}{7}$ and so on. In fact in this case $r(x,y)$ can be any number in $(0,\frac{1}{2})$.